# Run stored MS Access 2010 query via OLEDB

Tags: c#, ms-access

i have a MS Access 2010 database with a simple select query.

I am attempting to execute the query in C#, this would be easy with a 2003 database. Did something change besides the connection string?
I'm adding one parameter with value and setting CommandType = Stored Procedure.

Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source={0};

**This fails on "ExecuteReader" with "unspecified error"**

```
    public static OleDbDataReader ExecuteReader(string connString, CommandType cmdType, string cmdText, params OleDbParameter[] cmdParms)
    {
        OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand();
        OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection(connString);
        try
        {
            PrepareCommand(cmd, conn, null, cmdType, cmdText, cmdParms, ConnectionActionType.Open);
            OleDbDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            cmd.Parameters.Clear();
            return rdr;
        }
        catch
        {
            conn.Close();
            throw;
        }
    }
```

Comment: No, the process for Access 2010 is not significantly different from previous versions. FWIW, I just tested [this](http://pastebin.com/ENJa7Qkd) against Access 2010 and it worked fine for me.

Comment: Hmm...interesting, I can't tell, are you using the ACE12 provider?

Comment: Yes, `Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0`, same as you.

Comment: Ok, thanks for trying that out for me.  guess i need to figure out what is going on here.